# Way To Prevent To Redefine Constructor Definitions

Tags: c++, exception, methods, constructor

I am writing a custom Exception class, with some additional features over the `std::exception` one. I added a custom constructor `Exception(std::string details) : details(details) {}` to my Exception class.

Later, when I extend the `Exception` class, with the class `FileNotAccessibleException`, and throw it, I get a compile error saying `no matching function for call to ‘FileNotAccessibleException::FileNotAccessibleException(std::basic_string<char>)’` When I then add a method `FileNotAccessibleException(std::string details) : Exception(details) {}` to my class, it does work fine.

Is there no way to make the constructor work, without having to redefine the constructor for all my classes?

Comment: Yes, use inheriting constructors.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can inherit the constructors of the base class with a `using` declaration:

```
class FileNotAccessibleException : public Exception
{
 public:
    using Exception::Exception;
 ...
};
```

See more on inherited constructors on [Bjarne Stroustrup's C++11 FAQ](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#inheriting).

Note: this does not apply to pre-C++11 implementations, and was one of the last C++11 language features to be added to popular compilers such as G++ and CLANG.

Comment: One should mention that this is supported only since C++11, so if one can use it depends on the compilers one wants to support.

Comment: Also note that this feature was added pretty late to the C++11 support of some compilers, for example the default clang on OSX 10.8 doesn't support this constructor forwarding.

Comment: @AdamS Constructor forwarding usually refers to something else entirely, at least when I've seen it used. It could be either [delegating constructors](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/5894415f-be62-4bc0-81c5-3956e82276f3/entry/introduction_to_the_c_11_feature_delegating_constructors?lang=en), or just plain forwarding (`std::forward`) to a constructor, both of which were implemented in clang earlier than inheriting constructors. (And I agree with the actual point you're making.)

Comment: You forgot the semicolon in that statement.